# Markov chains and category theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, category-theory

Recently I learned about Markov chains. Consider a simple two-state Markov chain:

[image]

This looks like a categorical diagram, with states as objects, transition probabilities as morphisms/arrows, and of course, identities as the same state transition probabilities. Although I don't know much, I also came across connections between two separate Markov chains, implying a functor equivalence.

I wonder if there is such treatment in literature. Is there any benefit in approaching it this way?

Comment: It's just a weighted graph. There's no composition.

Comment: But there are some categories modelling stochastic things. Don't ask me, ask Google.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thats a good point. I tried imposing composition with time homogeneity but its not very clear.

Comment: Look up the Giry monad.